# Custom new google maps using api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have seen custom option for Google maps that users can add to their website. How can I make a map like this which shows info box as shown in the link below when you click on the location map on the right?

http://tinyurl.com/omgtqj4

http://tinyurl.com/oheq4ad

Can this be achieved using google maps api https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 0):

My very short answer: Yes you can. First example I think uses an embeded map though.

Comment: I know that he is using iframe  but if we can do same using google api, if yes can you please give any example or reference to a link .... fiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/3EfD8/1/

Comment: What exactly do you want to reproduce? The place card on the top left corner? Try to explain what you want to achieve and/or why you think you would need the API or an embeded map.